# Jquery values don't change when extracting table id's from a row dropped using two tables

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, html-table

I have the following jquery that allows me to drag and drop table rows between two tables.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{

    $("tbody.connectedSortable")
    .sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    appendTo: "parent",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    revert: "invalid",
    zIndex: 999990,
    receive: function (event, ui) 
    {            
        var data = $(this).attr('id');
        if(data == "table-draggable1")
        {
           $.ajax({ url: 'http://example.com/test.php?idservice='+ elementDropped.children(':first').text()+ '&stime=' + elementDropped.find("td:eq(3)").text() + '&etime=' + elementDropped.find("td:eq(4)").text()});   
          alert("foo");  
        }
        else if(data == "table-draggable2")
        {
           $.ajax({ url: 'http://example.com/test2.php?idservice='+ elementDropped.children(':first').text()+ '&stime=' + elementDropped.find("td:eq(3)").text() + '&etime=' + elementDropped.find("td:eq(4)").text()});   
          alert("bar");
        }
        return true;
    }
});
</script>
```

The problem is that 'data' is always equal to which ever table id I drag from first after refreshing the page and every drag after that produces the same id as the first drag. I am fairly new to JQuery so am i missing something fundamental with this?

Comment: Are the two tables being initially populated from a database or some other persistent storage option? If they are, are you updating the storage on drop? If not, the page will not retain it's state across GET requests.

Comment: @NateAnderson the tables are filled from a DB and within the if statement above i use ajax to update the tables in the database depending on which table has been dragged.

Comment: can you include some stripped down markup?

Comment: i have updated the code to show the ajax, it use two standard tables that are with a few divs nothing fancy, rows are filled out through a do while that loops the data needed.